# 4 to 20mA interface technologies

Tags: microcontroller, current, current-measurement

I'm researching solutions for reading the interface. 4 to 20 mA.

Today I only know the ADS1115 schematic solution below:

[image: ADC 4a20 ADS1115]

What are the solutions for reading this interface in a professional and reliable way, they could recommend integrated circuits.  interface with PIC microcontrollers

How can I digitally read a 4mA to 20mA signal into an ADC?

Comment: It has an I2C interface so just connect it to a micro with an I2C interface.

Comment: This seems to be for a 0-5V voltage input, not a current loop.  The voltage dividers at each analog input will attenuate a 5V signal down to 3.33V (for MCU compatibility).  The low-pass filters that follow will clean up noise, but this may not be suitable for your application.

Comment: you could use a current sensor like the INA219.

Answer (score 1):

Any ADC that reads voltage will work. Use a resistor to convert the current to a voltage then read the value with any ADC that uses voltage for an input.

For example: I have a sensor that outputs 4mA for it's min value and 20mA for it's max. If I chose an ADC that had an 0 to 5V input, I would select a resistor to get 5V at 20mA (using ohms law 5V/0.02A = 250Ω)

A 0 to 3.3V ADC (which are commonly fount on microprocessors) would be 3.3V/0.02A=165Ω (or you could make a voltage divider like the one in the circuit in the OP).